# Saving txt file going to wrong location

Tags: c#, winforms, streamwriter, savefiledialog

I'm trying to save a text file log to a specific location from my Windows Form project. I set the `InitialDirectory` to `Path.GetFullPath(filePath)` where I  pass in `filePath` which is set as a simple path of `"C:\MyWork\EventLogs\"`

The log saves on Exit of the program (when a user closes or hits an Exit button), but it still saves in the `Project\bin\Debug` folder of my project.

Any ideas would be great. Thanks!

```
try
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    string todayDate = today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm");
    string fileName = (todayDate + "_EventLog" + ".txt").Trim();
    string filePath = @"C:\MyWork\EventLogs\";
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
    SaveFileDialog sn = new SaveFileDialog
    {
        FileName = fileName,
        AddExtension = true,
        CheckPathExists = true,
        Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt",
        OverwritePrompt = true,
        InitialDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(filePath)
    };

    sn.RestoreDirectory = true;
    StreamWriter SaveFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
    foreach (var item in EventLog)
    {
        SaveFile.WriteLine(item);
    }
    SaveFile.Close();
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't show the save dialog or use its `FileName` property in your current code, instead you refer to the initial `fileName` when saving.

So what you need to do is something like this instead:

```
if (sn.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (StreamWriter SaveFile = new StreamWriter(sn.FileName))
    {
        foreach (var item in EventLog)
        {
            SaveFile.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This will display the save dialog and assuming that the user clicks on OK the `FileName` of the save dialog *should* be the full path of where the user wants to save to.

Answer (score -2):

You must show the Save Dialog for it to return the value you are expecting.